# Assembly Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagementfor SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document-set

I'm looking for the dll `Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement` for a project in SharePoint 2010 where there are `DocumentSet`

Where could I download this?

Answer (score 0):

To use this you need SharePoint Standard or Enterprise.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentset(v=office.14).aspx

The DLL will be placed in location

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI
```